# Changing the position of AIR-window (in AS3)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, window, position

I created a simple transparent app for Adobe AIR in Flash. It has not chrome, so now I need to make it draggable. How could this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is for the whole window draggable:

```
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove );

private function startMove( event : MouseEvent ) : void {
    stage.nativeWindow.startMove();
}
```

Other case, if you need just one little part of a window to accept MOUSE_DOWN event to start dragging, replace stage.addEventListener with movieClip.addEventListener and you are done.

Comment: I got this error: 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.